# Words with single quote and `MATCH AGAINST` accuracy

Tags: mysql, sql, select, full-text-search

How can i set mysql select to treat words without single quote same as if i searched them with single quote.
for example if i'm searching for `dont` treat it like `don't`

What I've tried

```
MATCH(title,short_story,full_story,dle_post.xfields) AGAINST ('dont') order by MATCH (title) AGAINST ('dont' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) desc LIMIT 0,22
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is in relation to your issue

[Full text query with a single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316209/full-text-query-with-a-single-quote)

I am almost certain dont or don't  is a stopword.

Comment: Ok, i assume you have reasons for that :) Hope the link helps you out.