# How to execute mysql fulltext search query having single quote in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I am using full text search the query is having single quote in where clause it returning values but not accurate.

```
SELECT `id`, `itemid`, `title`, 
MATCH( `itemid`, `title`, `product_id`,`p1_name`, `p2_name`, `p3_name`, `p4_name` ) 
AGAINST ( "men\'s" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score FROM `deals` 
WHERE `active_flag`='1' AND 
MATCH( `itemid`, `title`, `product_id`,`p1_name`, `p2_name`, `p3_name`, `p4_name`) 
AGAINST ( "men\'s" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) !=0 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

it should return the case where key word is exactly "Men's" (dont include " double quotes). but it is returning the cases where men and s exist?

can anybody help me out?

thanks.

Comment: i can only see on param with single quotes and it's a number so you don't even need quotes :) hope i got you right... otherwise i have to re-read your post ^^ its late and im at work :D

Comment: Did you set your ft_min_word_length to something other than the default? Its default is `4`, so `men` would never get indexed.

Comment: @Dwza see the line AGAINST ( "men\'s" IN BOOLEAN MODE ). i want results which has men's keyword i am taking param from user and user has entered men's.

Comment: @ Marc B yes its ft_min_word_length=2.

Comment: Try using paratheses `AGAINST ( "(men\'s)" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score FROM deals` and in the `AGAINST ( "(men\'s)" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) !=0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316209/full-text-query-with-a-single-quote

Comment: @kay nelson Does not work man...

Comment: What MySQL version are you running? Is it innodb or MyISAM fulltext?

Comment: For me its working. What if you put a `*` instead of a `\`. AGAINST ( "men*'s" IN BOOLEAN MODE )

Comment: @nelson i am running MyISAM

Comment: OK im running innodb fulltext and it works. I will keep trying with a MYISAM...

Comment: thanks man. i will wait. if possible please fiddle.

Comment: Managed to get it to work. It was the built in stopword list.

Comment: Did u have a chance to try it?

Answer (score 0):

Its most likley because of the internal stopword list for MyISAM fulltext.

According to [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

> The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the
>   stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The
>   server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute
>   path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing
>   the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file,
>   restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

I changed in my ini file this

```
+ft_stopword_file = C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/mysql_ft_stopword_file.txt
```

Then restart the server, it will start even if the file doesnt exists so you dont have to create one. You will have to rebuild the table after the restart.

I now managed to get results using this query

```
SELECT * FROM test.fttest 
WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST("men's" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

and this also

```
SELECT * FROM test.fttest 
WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST('men\'s' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It may be a good idea to later build your own stopword list if you have alot of data since no words are considered as stopwords so the indexes will get bigger.

Answer (score -1):

Escape a ' with two of them ''

```
  where name = 'men''s'
```

Comment: Yes, but that's mysql being compatible with other systems. Normal escaping is a backslash, and changing `men\'s` to `men''s` will NOT fix the problem. it's just reordering the deckchairs on the titanic.