# Searching MySql FullText Index with single quote

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to search for a string with single quote against a FullText index:

```
select * 
from gems 
where MATCH (gems.title, gems.descr) AGAINST ('"winter\'s discontent"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316209/full-text-query-with-a-single-quote) suggests that it should work, but it does not. When I changed that example from MyIsam to InnoDB, it no longer worked. Even in MyIsam, the query above would return a match on 'winter'

Any ideas?

I am using mySql 5.6.11 InnoDB

A sqlFiddle can be found [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2058/2) and it also does not work. It contains the following:

```
CREATE TABLE gems 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     title varchar(20), 
     descr varchar(100),
     FULLTEXT KEY `ft_title_descr` (`title`,`descr`)      
    );


INSERT INTO gems
(title, descr)
VALUES
('Post 1', 'Once upon a time'),
('Post 2', 'My winter\'s discontent');
```

Comment: Hmm interesting it could be something related to the engine try creating the table as myisam and here I created the fiddle it works now http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/828a9/1, and do not use double quote I have removed it.

Comment: The reason for the double quote is that it is a phrase and may contain multiple words. I am just simplifying it in the example. MyIsam will work - sort of (it also matches "winter") - but not an option for this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more Googling - seems this was a reported MySQL bug. I upgraded my mySQL version to 5.6.20 and this solved the problem.